# Valgrind Report Analysis :Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I was trying to analyse the report for valgrind. The report as as follows.Why Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s) is shown in the report several times.

```
=483== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==483==    at 0x4E7DA42: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E878C8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4005B2: main (p2.c:11)
==483==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==483==    at 0x40057D: main (p2.c:7)
==483== 
==483== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==483==    at 0x4E7CEDB: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E7DF55: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E878C8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4005B2: main (p2.c:11)
==483==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==483==    at 0x40057D: main (p2.c:7)
==483== 
==483== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==483==    at 0x4E7CEE5: _itoa_word (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E7DF55: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E878C8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4005B2: main (p2.c:11)
==483==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==483==    at 0x40057D: main (p2.c:7)
==483== 
==483== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==483==    at 0x4E7DFA4: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E878C8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4005B2: main (p2.c:11)
==483==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==483==    at 0x40057D: main (p2.c:7)
==483== 
==483== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==483==    at 0x4E7DB0D: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E878C8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4005B2: main (p2.c:11)
==483==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==483==    at 0x40057D: main (p2.c:7)
==483== 
==483== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==483==    at 0x4E7DB90: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4E878C8: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==483==    by 0x4005B2: main (p2.c:11)
==483==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==483==    at 0x40057D: main (p2.c:7)
```

The below is the sample code.

```
main()
{
    int *a,b;
    a=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a=b;
    printf("%d",*a);
}
```

Comment: It would help if we could see the code causing the this report.

Comment: You assign to `*a` the value of `b`; however, `b` has not been initialized (it is an automatic variable, which is allocated on the stack, and automatic variables are not initialized).

Comment: yeah,i got your point but why the report is reporting Conditional jump  several times.

Comment: The code in `printf` could do quite a lot of things depending on the value of the passed arguments. And since in this case the value of `*a` is uninitialized then you could get such errors.